# React Native unable to resolve module ../when

Tags: node.js, react-native, node-modules

I am trying to use the npm module when and installing it

> npm install when

when but for some reason it keeps saying it can not find it even though it's there. I have cleared all cache and rebuilt the project. This is the only module that gives any issues and it is saying when/dist/when doesn't exist.

```
import when from "when";
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try , `react-native link` and then do again react-native start /npm start and react-native run-android / run-ios. After i install a package i always restart everything

Comment: Thanks for the response but there is an issue with the package itself.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the paths in the **when** package for **React Native**. For example require('../lib/) should be require('../../lib/')

Answer (score 0):

Not all packages work with react-native, if it uses html/css or anything to do with a browser then it will not work.